# Mounting NFS share from Linux client on Windows domain

Tags: permissions, nfs, ldap, active-directory

I've got a client (Ubuntu 13.10) joined to a Windows domain through PBIS/Likewise, serving Samba shares and allowing domain users to login with domain credentials.

Outside of the Windows domain, there exists a network of Linux machines serving NFS shares and communicating UID/GID information over LDAP. From my client, I would like to preserve membership to the Windows domain and also be able to mount an NFS share from the Linux domain.

We'll say that I'd like to access the Windows domain with my credentials as stan/windows^group and the Linux domain with my credentials as stan/linux^group. The usernames are identical and cannot be changed.

Right now, I've installed nfs-common and I'm able to mount my NFS share while still participating as a Windows domain member. Listing the contents of the NFS share shows unrecognized UIDs/GIDs (i.e., 7513/7500 in lieu of stan/linux^group) and I have RO access.

I've tried installing an LDAP client and joining the Linux domain with it--This shows the correct user/group info, but hoses my ability to login as stan/windows^group (as anyone, actually. I uninstalled the LDAP client and rolled back my /etc/pam.d/common-* files to escape the problem). On top of that, I still couldn't write to the NFS share anyway.

What options are available to me? Can I mount the NFS share with a specific UID/GID? Alias multiple UIDs/GIDs to a single user on my client? I'm looking for a solution that I can share with other Linux users on my team, so hard-coding ID #s isn't preferred.

Note: Only settings on my client may be changed. Server-side configs are out of my hands.